# Adding invitation code to django registration

Tags: django, registration

Trying to add an invite code to django registration. I know there is a package for registration called invitation that would take care of it but it seems like it should Here is the code for registration forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Form for registering a new user account.

    Validates that the requested username is not already in use, and
    requires the password to be entered twice to catch typos.

    Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
    need, but should avoid defining a ``save()`` method -- the actual
    saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
    registration backend.

    """
    required_css_class = 'required'

    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                            max_length=30,
                            label=_("Username"),
                            error_messages={'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            label=_("Password"))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            label=_("Password (again)"))
i    code = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            label=_("Invitation Code"))

    def clean_username(self):
        """
        Validate that the username is alphanumeric and is not already
    in use.

        """
        existing = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        if existing.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("A user with that username already exists."))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']

    def clean(self):
    """
        Verifiy that the values entered into the two password fields
        match. Note that an error here will end up in
        ``non_field_errors()`` because it doesn't apply to a single
        field.

        """
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return self.cleaned_data

    def inviteCode(self):
        """
    Validate invitation code, ==happytimes
    """
    if 'icode' != 'happytimes':
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("You need a valid invite code to register, try again or contact us!"))
    else:
        return self.cleaned_data['icode']
```

I'm getting an integrityerror column user_id not unique. What am I doing wrong? The issue seems to have something to do with the sqlite3 db, but I can't be sure.

Per the request in the commment, here is the traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\views.py" in dispatch
  79.         return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\views.py" in post
  35.             return self.form_valid(request, form)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\views.py" in form_valid
  82.         new_user = self.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\backends\default\views.py" in register
  80.                                                                     password, site)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in inner
  224.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\models.py" in create_inactive_user
  88.         registration_profile = self.create_profile(new_user)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\models.py" in create_profile
  112.                            activation_key=activation_key)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in create
  137.         return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
  377.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in insert_query
  1593.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  912.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  40.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  344.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: column user_id is not unique
```

Here is, what I believe is the relevant section of models.py:

```
def create_inactive_user(self, username, email, password,
                             site, send_email=True):
        """
        Create a new, inactive ``User``, generate a
        ``RegistrationProfile`` and email its activation key to the
        ``User``, returning the new ``User``.

        By default, an activation email will be sent to the new
        user. To disable this, pass ``send_email=False``.

        """
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password,)
        new_user.is_active = False
        new_user.save()

        registration_profile = self.create_profile(new_user)

        if send_email:
            registration_profile.send_activation_email(site)

        return new_user
    create_inactive_user = transaction.commit_on_success(create_inactive_user)

    def create_profile(self, user):
        """
        Create a ``RegistrationProfile`` for a given
        ``User``, and return the ``RegistrationProfile``.

        The activation key for the ``RegistrationProfile`` will be a
        SHA1 hash, generated from a combination of the ``User``'s
        username and a random salt.

        """
        salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
        username = user.username
        if isinstance(username, unicode):
            username = username.encode('utf-8')
        activation_key = hashlib.sha1(salt+username).hexdigest()
        return self.create(user=user,
                           activation_key=activation_key)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback and, if you're using a custom user model, your model's code.

Comment: Traceback added. Its not a custom user model, I just want the invite code to return true and then fire off the rest of the code, which is to create the new user instance and then send the validation email.

Comment: It seems as if a registration profile for that specific user's id already exists. Did you somehow delete the user table and recreate it without emptying the registration profile table?

Comment: @knbk You are correct. No longer getting the IntegrityError. The function to validate the invitation code didn't run, but I think I can figure that out. Thanks!

Comment: Then you are also correct that it's a SQLite issue: SQLite3 by default does not check for the integrity of foreign key constraints. This allowed you to delete the user table in the first place without proper handling of the registration profile table.

Comment: Do you know if its the same issue in mysql? I am going to be using mysql when I move this to a production enviornment.

Comment: MySQL will raise an `IntegrityError` when you try to drop the user table and there are still registration profiles linked to existing users. Same for PostgreSQL and most other databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback indicates that a registration profile with said `user_id` already exists. This is most likely because the user table has been deleted (resetting the `auto_increment` status of the `id` column) but the registration profile's table has not been cleared. A newly generated `user_id` clashes with an older, removed `user_id`, which results in an `IntegrityError` because the `user_id` field in the registration profile's table is no longer unique.

This issue is generally only encountered with SQLite3, as foreign key constraints are not checked for integrity errors by default. This allows you to delete the `user` table or it's entries without deleting the registration profiles or setting the foreign key to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of the `icode` line.  You pasted it with a space.

Also, this logic is incorrect:

`if 'icode' != 'happytimes':`

You are comparing 2 strings.

And, I think you want to make `inviteCode` `clean_icode`, and run the logic there:

```
def clean_icode(self):
    """
    Validate invitation code, ==happytimes
    """
    if self.cleaned_data['icode'] != 'happytimes':
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("You need a valid invite code to register, try again or contact us!"))
   else:
        return self.cleaned_data['icode']
```

Comment: this makes sense. However, still no result. traceback has been added above.

Comment: Need to see models.py.  You probably need to add `user_id` to your Form